# Change localhost with port to domain name

Tags: java, tomcat

My webapp is built using JAVA(Backend) + JavaScript(FrontEnd) and I'm using Tomcat 8.0 as server.

Currently the URL to the webapp is "localhost:8083/myapp/index.jsp" and I have been trying to change it to a domain name in the hosts file (Under win/sys32/drivers/etc/..) and server.xml (under Tomcat) but unfortunately I wasn't able to achieve that. Any tips please?

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track, but what exactly did you change in the hosts file and what in server.xml? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just give a new port attribute value, do not add address attribute and should Tomcat be bind to all addresses. If you want to serve just one hostname give `address="192.168.1.2"` attribute.

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
           connectionTimeout="60000" redirectPort="443" 
           acceptCount="1000" acceptorThreadCount="2" maxConnections="10000" maxThreads="400"
           compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048"
           compressableMimeType="application/json, text/json, application/xml, text/xml"
           />

<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
           connectionTimeout="60000"
           acceptCount="1000" acceptorThreadCount="2" maxConnections="10000" maxThreads="400"
           keystoreFile="./keystore.jks" keystorePass="mypwd" keyAlias="tomcat" 
           SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048"
           compressableMimeType="application/json, text/json, application/xml, text/xml"
           />
```